# Cordova Connection type always returns unknown

Tags: cordova

In all androids smartphones I tested the command navigator.connection.type always returns unknown. Doesn't matter if I'm completely disconnected, using wifi or 3g

I installed the plugin via cmd -> cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.network-information

My versions are:

1. cordova 3.6.3-0.2.13
2. adb 1.0.31

Comment: please show your code for this, so we can help debug the issue

Answer (score 2):

the code is actually big, and the problem is configuration.

The thing is, i didnt actually solved anything.  Just recreated the project, copied the www folder in the new one, installed the plug ins again, re-did the config.xml and everything worked fine.

Even comparing the two projects i cant spot many noticiable diferences, but worked. I think this is a solution